# Hibernate not printing HQL in the log

Tags: hibernate

Hibernate is printing the HQL as **null** in the log files(Example below). The text printed looks like the summary of the query executed. How do I get it to print the actual HQL.

**HQL: null, time: 0ms, rows: 4**

Below is the code which results in this log statement

Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria( DataHolder.class );
criteria.setCacheable( true );
List data = criteria.add(Restrictions.naturalId().set( "sno", sno )).list();

**log4j config**
log4j.logger.org.hibernate=info

Comment: Please, provide some code as example.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to define hibernate to print the sql in the first place in `persistence.xml`

```
 <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
 <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true"/>
```

The latter is not needed, but useful

Comment: This property is already set to true. This will print the SQL queries on the console in the below pattern. "Hibernate: select ......". The log statement I mentioned looks more like a summary.